# Searching for SIP sequence diagram drawing tool

Tags: javascript, perl, sip, sequence-diagram

**Do you know any good JS or perl library to draw sequence diagram (in html, text or anything, really) from a CSV, pcap or any data type?**

I am implementing a voip traffic analysing perl script, and I would want to be able to graph a few calls.
I usually use wireshark, but I am working with huge chunks of data and I have to extract some stats out of it, making it impossible to use the [nice voip graphing tools](http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/093/9398/9398f3.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any in the languages you specify, but here is one in ANSI C ([mscgen](http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/)) and another Ubuntu package ([msc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/msc.1.html)).

Another approach that might work for you is to filter your large pcap file using something like [ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/). It supports regular expressions, and I wish I had known about it earlier. If it can filter the packets you need, then you can use wireshark to generate diagrams on the filtered results. I just found another tool in the same vein called [flowgrep](http://monkey.org/~jose/software/flowgrep/), but I haven't tried it myself.

**EDIT:** Just found a tool that accepts descriptions in the same format as mscgen and renders them via javascript: [mscgen_js](https://github.com/sverweij/mscgen_js)